# Unit testing in Universal App

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

I create new Universal App project, structure of the solution on screenshot.

[image]

After I add Unit Test App project for Windows Phone.

[image]

And see `Could not find SDK "MSTestFramework, Version=14.0"`

[image]

I'm use Visual Studio 2015 CTP

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2015 CTP
Version 14.0.22512.0 DP
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.6.00007
```

How to solve the problem?

Comment: That's strange. Just added a unit test app to one of my universal projects and it runs just fine.

Comment: what visual studio version?

Comment: thank you, it's probably problems 2015 CTP

Comment: Do those two assemblies exist on your machine? They should be under "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\WindowsPhoneApp\v8.1\ExtensionSDKs\MSTestFramework\12.0\" and "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\WindowsPhoneApp\v8.1\ExtensionSDKs\TestPlatform\12.0\" respectively.